# Definite integration, little bit tough with integration by parts.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, indefinite-integrals

The question is to find the following integral, where $n$, $L$ and $\pi$ are constants :

$$I = \frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} x^2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right) dx$$

I gave it a try and my answer is $I = \frac{L^2}{3}$, whereas the correct answer is $I = \left( \frac{1}{3} − \frac{1}{2n^{2}\pi^{2}} \right)L^2$. I've attached a picture of my work, please help me find what I am doing wrong.

[My working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLW6g.jpg)

Comment: @Mattos, you have edited it wrongly.  The final integral should be my final result

Comment: @SatishRamanathan No, I _didn't_ edit it incorrectly. I didn't remove anything the OP put in, I edited exactly what was originally written so it was clear and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last but one step should be integrated by parts again.

$I = 0 + \frac{L}{n\pi} \int x sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})dx$

Put $u = x$ and $dv = sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})dx$

$du = dx$ and $v = -\frac{L}{2n\pi} cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})$

Integration by parts

$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$

Thus $ I = -\frac{L^2}{2n^2\pi^2} x cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}) + \frac{L^2}{n\pi}\int cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})dx$

$ I = -\frac{L^2}{2n^2\pi^2} x cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}) + \frac{L^3}{2n^2\pi^2}  sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}) $

Now evaluate with L and 0

You get  $I = -\frac{L^3}{2n^2\pi^2} $

Now substitute in the first step you get

Integral $ = \frac{1}{L} \left[ \frac{L^3}{3} - \frac{L^3}{2n^2\pi^2}\right]$

And finally
Integral $ = \frac{L^2}{3} - \frac{L^2}{2n^2\pi^2}$